# add specific multiple rows (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I want to write a query to add multiple rows in a table.

For example:

Table:

```
matchid|player1id|player2id|player1score|player2score
101    |20       |10       |0           |100
101    |20       |10       |0           |100
101    |20       |10       |0           |100
201    |20       |10       |645         |0
201    |20       |10       |100         |700
201    |20       |10       |0           |100
```

Required output:

```
matchid|player1id|player2id|player1score|player2score
101    |20       |10       |0           |300
201    |20       |10       |745         |800
```

Note: I have to do this without using `GROUP BY`

Comment: `SELECT
 matchid,
 player1id,
 player2id,
 player1score = SUM(player1score),
 player2score = SUM(player2score)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
 matchid, player1id, player2id`

Comment: Why don't you want to use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: because its a costly operation

Comment: The alternatives are worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT matchid, player1id, player2id FROM tbl
) AS t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
        SUM(player1score), SUM(player2score)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE
        matchid = t.matchid
        AND player1id = t.player1id
        AND player2id = t.player2id
) AS x(player1score, player2score)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    matchid, player1is, player2id,
    SUM(player1score) as player1score,
    SUM(player2score) as player2score 
FROM 
    tablename 
GROUP BY
    matchid, player1id, player2id
```

Comment: thanks for the response kaushik. Sorry, I forgot to mention that i dont want to use group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
  select matchid,player1id,player2id,SUM(player1score) as 
player1score,SUM(player2score) as player2score 
FROM table1
Group by player1id,player2id, matchid
```

Comment: thanks for the response tshoemake. Sorry, I forgot to mention that i dont want to use group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy the requirement?:

```
select
    matchid, player1id, player2id,
    (select sum(player1score from Table t2 where t2.matchid = t.matchid) as player1score,
    (select sum(player2score from Table t2 where t2.matchid = t.matchid) as player2score
from
    (select distinct matchid, player1id, player2id from Table) t
```